The aws sdk java 2.x is printing necessary file contents when log level is set to DEBUG
We have a quarkus application that exposes api endpoint to receive request containing a file and uploads the file to S3 bucket.
When application root log level is set to DEBUG and when the request is sent , the application logs is printing information like the security token and the credentials and the file content and file name .
How can we disable this ?
we do not want the application logs to have these information even though the log level is set to DEBUG.
Below is the example log.
2024-09-23 06:38:15 DEBUG \[io.ne.ha.lo.LoggingHandler\] (aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-1) \[id: 0x775d66e9\] REGISTERED 2024-09-23 06:38:15 DEBUG \[io.ne.ha.lo.LoggingHandler\] (aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-1) \[id: 0x775d66e9\] CONNECT: test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/52.219.64.101:443 2024-09-23 06:38:15 DEBUG \[io.ne.ha.lo.LoggingHandler\] (aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-1) \[id: 0x775d66e9, L:/192.168.3.254:50328 - R:test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/52.219.64.101:443\] ACTIVE 2024-09-23 06:38:15 DEBUG \[io.ne.ha.lo.LoggingHandler\] (aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-1) \[id: 0x775d66e9, L:/192.168.3.254:50328 - R:test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/52.219.64.101:443\] WRITE: software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.NettyRequestExecutor$StreamedRequest(DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1) PUT /0148ffa2-52c0-11ec-ae45-02b72c6380ad/1727073495061-testfile.txt HTTP/1.1 Host: test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com amz-sdk-invocation-id: d455aa4e-4a17-0a54-8340-12aeaa515ab2 amz-sdk-request: attempt=1; max=4 Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIA3NWURXFPB7MDWNVL/20240923/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-meta-contenttype;x-amz-meta-uploadedfilename;x-amz-security-token, Signature=50f108e5685ad5ea34e668e386d34a7d503e99e8b2339eb4eba8b6eb3022296 Content-Length: 58

I tried using the log4j2 properties to filter the logs with certain keywords  like below:
## \<Appenders\>

## \<!-- Console appender --\>

## \<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"\>

## \<PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p \[%c{2.}\] (%t) %s%e%n"/\>

## \<!-- Regex filter to block specific DEBUG logs --\>

## \<Filters\>

## \<RegexFilter regex="^.\*\\\[so.am.aw.requestId\\\].\*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/\>

## \<RegexFilter regex="^.\*\\\[so.am.aw.co.in.ExecutionInterceptorChain\\\].\*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/\>

## \<RegexFilter regex="^.\*\\\[so.am.aw.request\\\].\*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/\>

## \<RegexFilter regex="^.\*\\\[so.am.aw.co.in.ht.pi.st.AsyncSigningStage\\\].\*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/\>

## \<RegexFilter regex="^.\*\\\[so.am.aw.ht.au.aw.in.si.DefaultV4RequestSigner\\\].\*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/\>

## \<!-- Filter to exclude DEBUG level logs --\>

## \<LevelFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/\>

## \</Filters\>

## \</Console\>

## \</Appenders\>

But that also didnot help.
I even tried using java class to filter specific logs still it is not working below is the example:
// Define the patterns you want to block/mask
private static final String[] BLOCK_PATTERNS = {
        "so.am.aw.requestId",
        "so.am.aw.co.in.ExecutionInterceptorChain",
        "so.am.aw.request",
        "so.am.aw.co.in.ht.pi.st.AsyncSigningStage",
        "so.am.aw.ht.au.aw.in.si.DefaultV4RequestSigner",
        "sof.ama.aws.requestId",
        "sof.ama.aws.request",
        "sof.ama.aws.cor.int.ExecutionInterceptorChain",
        "sof.ama.aws.htt.aut.aws.int.sig.DefaultV4RequestSigner",
        "sof.ama.aws.cor.int.htt.pip.sta.SigningStage"
};

protected LogMaskingConverter(String name, String style) {
    super(name, style);
}

// This method is used by Log4J's engine. Do not remove it.
public static LogMaskingConverter newInstance(final Configuration config, final String[] options) {
    return new LogMaskingConverter("maskLogs", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

@Override
public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder outputMessage) {
    // Retrieve the log message
    String messageString = event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();

    // Check if the message contains any blocked pattern
    for (String pattern : BLOCK_PATTERNS) {
        if (messageString.contains(pattern)) {
            // Mask or block the log message by replacing it with a placeholder
            outputMessage.append("[SENSITIVE DATA MASKED]");
            return;
        }
    }

    // If no pattern matches, append the original log message`your text`
    outputMessage.append(messageString);


You won't find "so.am.aw.request" in your log messages, because it is not part of the log message. The log message is only the part of the log event, that describes what happened, e.g. "[id: 0x775d66e9] REGISTERED" and is printed by the %m pattern converter. See Messages for more details.
The "so.am.aw.request" is the abbreviated form of the name of the logger ("software.amazon.awssdk.request"). Each logger can be configured separately (see Logger Configuration) and all you need to do is to configure it to a level more severe than DEBUG. Amazon has a guide on wire logging that tells you which loggers you need to enable or disable.
<Loggers>
  ...
  <!--
    ~ Loggers involved in wire logging,
    ~ do **NOT** enable `DEBUG` on production.
    --> 
  <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk.request" level="WARN" />
  <Logger name="io.netty.handler.logging" level="WARN" />
  <Logger name="io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2FrameLogger" level="WARN" />
</Loggers>


Thanks for your solution sir , let me add some more clarification to the question,
we have externalize the log levels in the application.properties, values.yaml .  According to Log4j2, it can filter the unnecessary message body.  Can you please clear that even if we set the log level manually to a level higher than DEGUB or  , and the same in application.properties, still , if someone has access to the project they can make the log level to DEBUG again right? and will see the data,
is there no way that using this log4j2 we can remove the extra data form the logs, or remove the log itself

kindly have a look at the flow diagram for a reference

@Bogan: the configuration file must be a trusted source. If an attacker can modify the configuration file, he can do much more damage that enable DEBUG on some loggers.

Please take a look at this flow diagram for your reference , this is what we are trying to achieve
